# Playwright doesn't fully load the webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping, playwright, playwright-python

So I just started learning about playwright today(plan on creating reviews scraper) but I instantly ran into a problem of it not being able to fully launch a page and therefore perform a task.

I got this super simple code:

```
from playwright.sync_api import Playwright, sync_playwright, expect
import time

def run(playwright: Playwright) -> None:
    browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    context = browser.new_context()
    page = context.new_page()
    page.goto("https://www.fiverr.com/")

    time.sleep(2)
    page.mouse.wheel(0, 4000)
    time.sleep(10)

    # ---------------------
    context.close()
    browser.close()


with sync_playwright() as playwright:
    run(playwright)
```

It opens a browser, Fiverr's page opens but there is still a loading page animation in a FAVICON section. When I try to open the website from a regular browser it works fine and I don't face any problems.

I don't think this is a problem(who knows) but I'm from Russia) It seems to be a reason to lots of problems haha

Comment: Many sites try to block automated browsing, so this is pretty normal. You may try adding a user agent header. Your code works for me (USA) so it could be a regional thing.